# php-pdftk Mutlple Files

Tags: php, pdf, pdftk, php-pdftk

I am using [php-pdftk](https://github.com/mikehaertl/php-pdftk) to generate pdf files. I am attempting to create multiple pdf's, but this only generates 1 file. Here is an example of what I am doing.

```
$pdf = new Pdf( 'file1.pdf' );
$pdf->send('test1.pdf');

$pdf2 = new Pdf( file2.pdf' );
$pdf2->send('test2.pdf');
```

This only outputs test1.pdf and I cannot get it to output both. Does anybody know how to do this? Thanks

Comment: There are two typos in your code snippet:
 1. Missing a quote mark around files2.pdf on line 3
 2. On line3 you reuse `$pdf` when I suspect it should be `$pdf2`

Comment: Thank you. Typos fixed. This code was not the actual code that was running, just some demo code. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to send more than one file (independent to the file type) in a single HTTP response.

You may try to zip the resulting files and send this instead.

Comment: I'm not sure if the usage of e.g. the [ZipArchive](http://php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php) class would be a good answer to your initial question - you didn't asked for this.